# Pointer to a 2 D Array

Tags: c++, typedef, multidimensional-array

Let's say i have a 2 D array int m[3][4]
If the typedef is defined as

```
typedef int array[4];
array *ptr = m;
```

What does this mean? Is it pointer to array of 4 elements. Or array of 4 pointers?

When we `cout << ptr or cout << *ptr`, It prints the same address. How is that possible?

Comment: `ptr` is a pointer to array of 4

Comment: cout << ptr or cout << *ptr; But are printing address on my ubuntu system.
But when I run the same code on codepad.org *ptr printf [1,2,3,4]; (m is a array of 4 ints {1,2,3,4} can any body explain this difference in the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ptr is pointer to an array of four elements of type int. m is an array of 3 elements of type (of array of four elements of type int). To give you a picture - m is an array of 3 elements of type array. And that is the reason when ptr is initialized to m - there is no problem because 'm' being an array is implicitly converted to pointer to first element in that array.

ptr is pointer to an array of elements. So that pointer is printed. And when *ptr is used - you get an array which again get's implicitly converted to pointer to the first element of the array, which again is the same starting point - so you get the same value.

As everything starts at the same point you are getting the same value. Thing will start differentiating when one does ++ on pointers. I will leave you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html). After reading this you can read the declaration as being a pointer to the type-alias `array`, in other words a pointer to an array of four integers.

Answer (score 0):

As per "clockwise/spiral rule" ptr is a pointer to array of 4 int.